# how to add the 0 to the the array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
  var months = range(1, 12);
```

I am trying to generate numbers between 1 to 12 by using above snippet I am getting the result

```
[   {
        label: '1',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        label: '2',
        value: '2',
    },   .....  {
        label: '12',
        value: '12',
    }, ]
```

like this But I want output something like this

```
  [   {
        label: '01',
        value: '01',
    },
    {
        label: '02',
        value: '02',
    },   .....  {
        label: '12',
        value: '12',
    }, ]
```

how to achieve output like this.

this is my range function

```
function range(start, end) {
        return Array(end - start + 1)
            .fill()
            .map((_, idx) => ({
                label: start + idx,
                value: start + idx,
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Hint: [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

Comment: Where is your 'range' function?

Comment: range.map(r => r.toString().padStart(2, '0'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
function range (start, end) { 
  const arr = [];
  for(var i = start; i<=end; i++) {
    const value = i.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    arr.push({label: value, value});
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Usage

```
range(1,12)
```

Comment: I got the response ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"] can you let me know how to get the response like this  {
            label: '01',
            value: '01',
        },
        {
            label: '02',
            value: '02',
        },

Comment: ill have update my question please check it

Comment: thank you so much  I have got expected behaviour.

Comment: since my reputation is less its not taking , but I accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

const array = [...Array(13).keys()] // creating array from 0 to 13
array.shift() // deleting the first element of an array which is 0 unwanted element for us
const months = array.map(month => month >= 10 ? month : '0'+month) // checks every value of the array if value is greater or equals to 10 , we add 0 to it